# Change external ip to be the one of a server?

Tags: linux, ssh

I can ssh from my computer (Ubuntu 14.04) to a RedHat server. I wonder if I can browse webpages in Google Chrome or Firefox using the external IP address of the server?

Running firefox on the server and after `ssh -X` to the server is very slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Proxy through SSH: https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html

Comment: Most browsers allow you to configure a proxy...